# Как передать переменную из ajax в php?

Tags: php, ajax

Есть вот такой javascript, который передает в файл action_cat переменную num. Как мне передать таким же образом переменную cat? Что, где дописать?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#imgLoad").hide(); // Скрываем прелоадер
});
var num = 15; //чтобы знать с какой записи вытаскивать данные
var cat = 3; // категория
$(function() {
    $("#load div").click(function(){ // Выполняем если по кнопке кликнули

        $("#imgLoad").show(); // Показываем прелоадер

        $.ajax({
            url: "/func/action_cat.php", // Обработчик
            type: "GET",       // Отправляем методом GET
            data: {"num": num},
            cache: false,           
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 0){ // Смотрим ответ от сервера и выполняем соответствующее действие
                    alert("Больше нет записей");
                    $("#imgLoad").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#content").append(response);
                    num = num + 5;
                    $("#imgLoad").hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да тоже самое:

```
        type: "GET",       // Отправляем методом GET
        data: {"num": num, "cat": cat},
        cache: false,
```

У вас всё для этого уже есть.